# Setting a timeout and finishing an ActivityforResult activity

Tags: android, android-activity, onactivityresult

I'd like to know if there's some way to set a timeout for an Intent started via startActivityForResult, so when the time is passed some actions can be performed with the activity of the mentioned intent (in my case finishing it).

There doesn't seem to be any direct way to set a timeout directly to the Intent, but this doesn't look too much to worry about, as I guess I could create a CountDownTimer that in onFinish() would call the code to finish the intent.

Problem is I don't see a way to finish that ActivityForResult.

Is there any way to do this?

Comment: Is it "your" Activity from which you are trying to get some "result"? (As opposed to some anonymous Activity which the users may pick, e.g. for taking a photo)

Comment: @0X0nosugar No, it's an anonymous Activity, indeed an ACTION_PICK one. If it were mine I'd just have to set the CountDownTimer in the called activity and I'll finish itself when time comes.

Comment: Best practice would be to set your timeout mechanism inside your child activity (you can pass some information in your intent) setResult(TIMEOUT).

Comment: @Sahil How could I could set that mechanism inside an anonymous activity? Maybe it can be overloaded, but I see no way.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, I finally got to solve the problem, indeed it wasn't very difficult.

For my particular case of INTENT_PICK the following code is valid to stop the activity after 2 minutes:

```
final int RQS_PICKCONTACT = 1;

[...]
Intent intentPickContact = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK, uriContact);

                        startActivityForResult(intentPickContact, RQS_PICKCONTACT);

                        mcd = new CountDownTimer(120000, 10000) {

                            public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {

                            }

                            public void onFinish() {
                                try
                                {
                                    finishActivity(RQS_PICKCONTACT);

                                }
                                catch (Exception ex)
                                {

                                }
                            }

                        }.start();
```

Comment: You solved my million dollar problem. Thanks a lot buddy.

Answer (score 0):

In my case I wanted to limit the time a user was doing a task so I created my own timer class.

```
public class Timer {

private static final String TAG = "Timer" ;
int timeout;
Context mContext;
boolean compleatedTask;
String timeoutKey;
CountDownTimer countDown;

public Timer(Context mContext, int timeout, String timeoutKey){

    this.timeout = timeout;
    this.mContext = mContext;
    this.timeoutKey = timeoutKey;
}

public void startTimer() {


    this.countDown = new CountDownTimer(this.timeout, 1000) {

        public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {

            Log.i(TAG, "OnTick, context: " + mContext + ", milisUntilFinished: " + millisUntilFinished + ", compleatedTask: " + compleatedTask);

            if(compleatedTask)
                cancel();
        }

        public void onFinish() {

            Log.i(TAG, "OnFinish, context: " + mContext  + ", compleatedTask: " + compleatedTask);

            try
            {
                if(!compleatedTask){

                    Intent intent = new Intent(mContext, UnsuccessfullPosTaskActivity.class);
                    intent.putExtra("error", StateMachine.databaseAccess.getDictionaryTranslation(timeoutKey, StateMachine.language));
                    mContext.startActivity(intent);
                }

            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                ex.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

    };

    countDown.start();

}

public void setCompleatedTask(boolean compleatedTask){
    this.compleatedTask = compleatedTask;

    if(compleatedTask)
        countDown.onFinish();
}
```

}

Then in your activity

```
int timeout = 1000;
Timer timer = new Timer(Activity.this, timeout);
timer.startTimer(); 

//do stuff

if(conditionToStop)
timer.setCompleatedTask(true);
```

And if you are using recycle views and you want to stop the counter when they click an option just send the timer object to your custom recycle view adapter.