# Setting timeout on activity launched using registerForActivityResult

Tags: android

I am using Activity Result APIs introduced in AndroidX Activity.

Is there any way we can kill/finish an activity launched using `registerForActivityResult` on timeout before we get any result?

[Similar Question based on Activity Class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51159229/setting-a-timeout-and-finishing-an-activityforresult-activity), suggests correctly that we can use `finishActivity(resultCode)` for finishing activity on timeout.

I was unable to do same for newer AndroidX API.

Thanks in advance.